# If we are talking about last night which one is correct to say

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, word-meaning, phrase-usage

*I haven't slept much today* or *I haven't slept much yesterday.*

When we are reffering to the night that was between today and yesterday.

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to say it this way? By definition, "to*day*" and "yester*day*" refer to "*day*time".

Answer (score 2):

The word "**today**" isn't correct in this context. However, "**yesterday**" can be used to refer to the night before today.

When we are referring to the night that was between yesterday and today we say "**last night**":

- I slept well last night.

Present Perfect in your example, however, doesn't work with a fixed time period (last night/yesterday). I'd say something like:

- I didn't get enough sleep last night.
- I didn't sleep much last night.
- I didn't get a lot of sleep yesterday.

Comment: I've never heard anyone say _"the night before today"_, they would just say _"last night"_. I guess they might say _"the night before yesterday"_, but _"the night before last"_ would be much more common.

Answer (score 1):

> It is Noon on Tuesday.  I went to sleep at 11 pm on Monday and woke up at 3 am on Tuesday.  ***"I didn't sleep much last night."***

Last night is over, there is no chance that I will sleep more last night, so I use the simple past tense. (Preterite)

> It is Noon on Wednesday.  I went to sleep at 11 pm on Monday and woke up at 3 am on Tuesday.  ***"I didn't sleep much night before last."***

To refer to the previous night, I say "night before last."  Again I use simple past.

> It is 5 PM on Tuesday.  I was discharged from the hospital on Sunday and told by my doctor to rest for several days while I recover from my dorsal fin transplant.  Yesterday, I slept most of the day, but ***I haven't slept much today***.

Yesterday is finished, so I use simple past.  Today is ongoing, and I could conceivably sleep more, so I use the present perfect.